# Read property in Json in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem. How can I get **refcat** in that **Json object in javascript**. Please find the below code snippet.

```
{
  "request": {
    "operation": "Viviendas",
    "languague": "es",
    "idMunicipio": "5",
    "idVia": "196",
    "idProvincia": "28",
    "pc1": "9115501",
    "pc2": "VK6891N",
    "numero": "1"
  },
  "created_http": "Thu Oct 01 09:33:58 GMT+01:00 2015",
  "created_server": 20151001092458,
  "data": [
    {
      "portal": "",
      "escaleras": [
        {
          "escalera": "1",
          "plantas": [
            {
              "planta": "00",
              "puertas": [
                {
                  "puerta": "01",
                  "refCat": "9115501VK6891N0001GB",
                  "superficieVivienda": 60.0,
                  "superficieTotal": 60.0
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "planta": "01",
              "puertas": [
                {
                  "puerta": "01",
                  "refCat": "9115501VK6891N0002HZ",
                  "superficieVivienda": 154.0,
                  "superficieTotal": 170.0
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "planta": "02",
              "puertas": [
                {
                  "puerta": "01",
                  "refCat": "9115501VK6891N0003JX",
                  "superficieVivienda": 161.0,
                  "superficieTotal": 177.0
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "page": "1",
  "pagesTotal": "1",
  "status_code": "200",
  "status_text": "OK"
}
```

I tried to fix this with the below method.

```
alert(json.data[0].escaleras[0].plantas[0].puertas[i].refCat);
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you iterating through the json object! if so could you please post the loop?

Comment: It will depend on the way you are using the data... I believe we will have multiple records

Comment: @Gonzalo what do you see in that alert instead of value of the `refCat`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'get the refcat object'. Do you need just a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you would have to iterate through the json object to get the data.

Use the following code.

```
json.data.forEach(function (object) {
    object.escaleras.forEach(function (innerObject) {
        innerObject.plantas.forEach(function (innerMostObject) {
            innerMostObject.puertas.forEach(function (refCatObject) {
                console.log(refCatObject.refCat)
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
alert(json.data[0].escaleras[0].plantas[0].puertas[i].refCat);
                    i is causing the problem...... ^
```

it should be `0`.

```
alert(json.data[0].escaleras[0].plantas[0].puertas[0].refCat);
```

```js
var json =     {
      "request": {
        "operation": "Viviendas",
        "languague": "es",
        "idMunicipio": "5",
        "idVia": "196",
        "idProvincia": "28",
        "pc1": "9115501",
        "pc2": "VK6891N",
        "numero": "1"
      },
      "created_http": "Thu Oct 01 09:33:58 GMT+01:00 2015",
      "created_server": 20151001092458,
      "data": [
        {
          "portal": "",
          "escaleras": [
            {
              "escalera": "1",
              "plantas": [
                {
                  "planta": "00",
                  "puertas": [
                    {
                      "puerta": "01",
                      "refCat": "9115501VK6891N0001GB",
                      "superficieVivienda": 60.0,
                      "superficieTotal": 60.0
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "planta": "01",
                  "puertas": [
                    {
                      "puerta": "01",
                      "refCat": "9115501VK6891N0002HZ",
                      "superficieVivienda": 154.0,
                      "superficieTotal": 170.0
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "planta": "02",
                  "puertas": [
                    {
                      "puerta": "01",
                      "refCat": "9115501VK6891N0003JX",
                      "superficieVivienda": 161.0,
                      "superficieTotal": 177.0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "page": "1",
      "pagesTotal": "1",
      "status_code": "200",
      "status_text": "OK"
    };
alert(json.data[0].escaleras[0].plantas[0].puertas[0].refCat);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you had a div with the id 'test' , this works.  I'd guess it's your indexing logic generating the [i] on 'puertas' that's not correct,  or perhaps your 'json' object isn't actually a JSON Object?

example jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p6udz7ao/

copy of example below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonString = '{ "request": { "operation": "Viviendas", "languague": "es" ,"idMunicipio":"5","idVia":"196","idProvincia":"28","pc1":"9115501","pc2":"VK6891N","numero":"1" }, "created_http": "Thu Oct 01 09:33:58 GMT+01:00 2015", "created_server": 20151001092458, "data": [ { "portal": "", "escaleras": [ { "escalera": "1", "plantas": [ { "planta": "00", "puertas": [ { "puerta": "01", "refCat": "9115501VK6891N0001GB", "superficieVivienda": 60.0, "superficieTotal": 60.0 } ] } , { "planta": "01", "puertas": [ { "puerta": "01", "refCat": "9115501VK6891N0002HZ", "superficieVivienda": 154.0, "superficieTotal": 170.0 } ] } , { "planta": "02", "puertas": [ { "puerta": "01", "refCat": "9115501VK6891N0003JX", "superficieVivienda": 161.0, "superficieTotal": 177.0 } ] } ] } ] } ], "page" : "1", "pagesTotal" : "1", "status_code" : "200", "status_text" : "OK" }';

    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    var refcattext = jsonObject.data[0].escaleras[0].plantas[0].puertas[0].refCat;

    $('#test').text(refcattext);
});
```